# How do I combine multiple query parameters in Wordpress WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do execute a query with multiple parameters and can't figure out how to properly format the query. There isn't any documentation on combining queries in [codex.wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

I need to have the following in the query:

- category id - to only show posts from a certain cateogry (or categories, array)
- number of posts per page
- order by date DESC
- exclude a post using a post id

Here is my attempt:

```
   <?php
   $query = new WP_Query('cat=4', array('posts_per_page' => '4'), array('orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC'));
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ( $query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        </li>
  <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, nothing</p>
  <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&` to separate parameters like in URL GET parameters:

`new WP_Query('cat=4&posts_per_page=4&orderby=date&order=DESC')`

Or you can supply an array parameter:

```
new WP_Query(array(
    'cat' => 4,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
))
```

Comment: Sergiu, that works great. Thank you. How would I pass in multiple categories? Would I pass in an array into that hash or define the whole 'cat' => x multiple times?

Comment: Pass it in as an array.